# jQuery scroll down pop up window page and not the main html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

We have html page with a pop up that gets opened on button click. Both html page and pop up have scroll bar for them.

I want pop up window to scroll down on click of a button that is inside the pop up.

I am doing:
$(window).scrollTop($('#suggestDetails').offset().top);

The element #suggestDetails is inside the pop up but the main html page scroll bar gets down on button click and not the pop up scroll bar.

Any idea how to move down scroll bar/screen inside the pop up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to scroll the popup/modal, not the window.

```js
$('#yourmodal-id').scrollTop($('#suggestDetails').offset().top);
```